# Filtering DataGridview using DataSet -> BindingSource, extra columns later added

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, filtering, bindingsource

For a WinForms VB.Net application, I use the Bindingsource's filtering capacity to filter data, which is seen in a DataGridview. The BindingSource is from a DataSet, created using the Designer, and the data comes from a Access DB, using JetEngine and .Net 3.5. So basically:

```
Datagridview.Datasource = xxBindingSource
xxBindingsource.Filter = "[extended filter string with multiple columns]"
```

This filtering works fine, however, now I included some extra columns in the DataGridView, which I'd like to filter on, too. Of course, when I feed the manually added columns to the Filter of the BindingSource, this doesn't work out.

I've done some research, and was not able to find any way to use the BindingSource's filtering syntax on the DataGridview. I'd like to use this syntax though, as I designed quite a nice UserControl and class around it, to provide smooth, fast and simple filtering capabilities. Any suggestions here?

Another option would be to rewrite this part, and use some other form of filtering. Can anyone point me to some best practices?

Comment: Have you tried adding those columns to your `DataSet` before you bind it?

Comment: Can I add a column to a DataSet which has a Access DB for a source? I don't need this column to end up in the DB itself, for it contains no extra information, just some calculated/acquired values.

Comment: The `DataSet` is just an object in memory after its retrieved from the database, you can do whatever you want to it. The only place you'd run into trouble is if you were updating the database using the dataset and generated update statement that wouldn't be aware of your changes.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for replying! Well, this is really the thing: I use the dataset in memory to update the DB. Using simply a tableadapter, and sending the .GetChanges with it per table. Is it do-able to alter this to allow the addition of the column in the DataSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Jack got it right! I learned about the DataColumn.Expression and about adding a column to the DataTable in the DataSet, which didn't affect the TableAdapter. So I did just that. Great, thanks!